# DataFlow Batch Jobs and Quotas

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When submitting many jobs, I get an error similar to

```
Project <my project> has insufficient quota(s) to execute this workflow
```

Since this is a batch job, why is my job not held until resources are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding it until the resources are available isn't always the best solution -- that may never happen depending on your total quota, behavior of other workloads, etc.

But having an option to do so seems like it could be a useful feature -- will note your request.

Comment: Thanks for the response!